# Bind User Selection To Instance Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, filter

Rails 3 Ruby 1.9

My app has a standard controller setup with an @products instance variable set to show all products by default  and @auto and @home variables set to select those products with a "type" of Auto or Home like so:

```
 @products= Product.all
 @auto = Product.where(:type =>"Auto")
 @home = Product.where(:type =>"Home")
```

my view uses a select_tag to allows users to select a product type like so:

```
 <%=select_tag "dept-filter", options_from_collection_for_select(@products, "id", "dept"), :prompt => "All Departments"%>
   <%@products.each do |product|%>
    do some stuff here 
    <%end%>
```

I am trying to figure out how to bind the users selection to the "type" variables (@auto and @home) and then set the @products variable equal to the "type" variable selected.

For example if a user selects "Home" as his product type the app should then set @products = @home